# Excel XML Export Failing

Tags: xml, excel

I am new to XML. I am trying to generate xml data from from and excel file to import into an Adobe Indesign workflow. I have done several simple exports without any trouble but now that I am doing it on a larger scale I'am running into problems. When I verify map for export its says "A mapped element's relationship with other elements cannot be preserved." Here is a link to the xml and spreadsheet involved. Yes I have read Microsoft's documentation on import and export of xml. I have seen where it lists possible reasons for this error but it mostly goes over my head. Here is a link to the files involved.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5cm4cpfH2d1UTZ6NzQwSXFwc0U&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your project but couldn't you consider using Datamerge and tabbed text export format ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Somehow the content I was wanting to export were in two separate tables. So I copied the content and and pasted it as values into a new sheet. That fixed the problem.